# How often is the checkpoint period for structured streaming, and is it configurable?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, offset, spark-structured-streaming

I'm in the process of making the case for our data forwarding job to switch from Spark batch to structured streaming. We use a Kafka source and a `foreach` sink composed of socket connections.

With batch streaming I tried to enforce exactly-once semantics by storing the offset in zookeeper on every ACK back from a socket, but it's been prone to outage with production throughput a couple times a week most likely due to our offset management. I've now taken note from a frequent poster, Jacek Laskowski, regarding offset management:

> You simply should not be dealing with this low-level "thing" called offsets that Spark Structured Streaming uses to offer exactly once guarantees.

I understand that since sockets are not idempotent, we cannot guarantee exactly once semantics through HDFS checkpointing. I've read that for structured, the offset will be checkpointed every trigger, but during a trial run without checkpointing I was seeing trigger durations every 25ms.

Would structured streaming really be able to store the offset every 25ms, and is this checkpoint period configurable from a structured streaming perspective? Keep in mind I have not installed HDFS on our spark workers yet, so if it's a simple configuration from the HDFS side than I apologize for the long question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the trigger frequency as below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger    
val query = resultTable
          .writeStream
          .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
          .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://path/to/checkpoints")
          .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
          .foreach(writer)
          .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```